# Disown process from cygwin bash

Tags: bash, cygwin

There is a way to properly disown process from cygwin bash?

for example i can run in background

```
/cygdrive/c/Windows/notepad.exe &
```

and the notepad window shows but when i close the bash using Ctrl+D or typing exit the bash window remain open

Comment: Did you try `disown`?

Comment: Sorry, Not a programming question. Voting to move to Superuser.com. Good luck.

Comment: using disown the job is removed by job list but the problem remains: the windows never close until i close the notepad.exe

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`cygstart notepad`

Or, if you're using [mintty](http://mintty.googlecode.com):

`setsid notepad`

(`setsid` is in the util-linux package.)

Comment: it's work, but how can i do if i already started the notepad? there is a command like disown?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do disassociate a running process.

Comment: ditto ak2 if I run say calc doesnt seem to matter if nohup or disown calc dies if I close the parent window

Answer (score 0):

I'd try with `nohup` as explained in this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/673333/183066) to a similar question.